# Cleaning db entities after test

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, autotest

I'm writing an autotest(with java maven+junit+cucumber)

- Before the start of testcase I need to create a user for test and some entities in db(lets name them entity1 and entity2)
- During the testcase I create entity3 by clicking "create" button in UI(entity3 is connected to entity1 as many to one)
- After the end of testcase I need to clean up(which means to delete all the data that I created before the test and all the data created from ui during the test)

Now I try to make some delete queries to db after the end, but face some problems:

1. Tables are connected between each other and by the end of the test I have a bunch of rows in the other tables that reference to my initial entity1 and entity2 and need to cascade delete them and that takes a lot of time, eventually it will lead to after method taking more time than test itself
2. Tables are not specified on cascade delete and I cant change it since it is expected behavior
3. it is dev environment that is used for manual tests also so I cant just delete all data, I need to delete only what is created by autotest

I know there is some hibernate thing but I have never used it and Im not sure if It can make what I need

Im looking for some options were I can save how db was before test then do test and then revert all what happend to db so it is same as it was before test

Comment: An in-memory database allows you to keep test data separate from dev environment data - I prefer this for unit tests so that devs interactions don't mess with a running test; JPA can help with DDL generation to create tables on start up, and can drop the tables on demand as well. You can use the same behavior to create tables in a test specific schema in any database as well though. Otherwise, tests should have before/after setup methods that track exactly what they create and clean it up after - Sometimes in suites if they take more time to run.

Comment: If cleanup takes that much time, you'll want to figure out why exactly. Is the DB indexed correctly, are other processes running concurrently slowing down locks, can the delete statements be optimized? If it takes longer for your tests, it might mean something you overlooked that might affect production down the road. Cascade delete can help, but the cost of an extra statement shouldn't be 'that' high if you do it manually. Tests I write try to use bulk deletes for cleanup, using test specific keys for all data. I try not to rely on the model (cascades) or DB for clean up as they can change.

Comment: I can't use in-memory database, because these are end-to-end tests, not unit tests, I am using selenide to do stuff on the website (dev environment) I need my entities to be on dev in order to check dev behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do that. Probably both are not „the best”, but works.

1. Hibernate has a feature called initial import, that use `import.sql` file. You need to recreate database before each test. This solution is ancient, and difficult to maintain in an environment with multiple tests.
2. You can use a combination of [Liquidbase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/). Then each test will start with a separated DB from docker container. Testcontainer will be set up database and liquidbase/flyway will fill it.
3. Use an old library called [DBUnit](https://gitlab.com/dbUnit/dbunit-extension) with some [extensions](https://github.com/rmpestano/dbunit-rules) for Junit5.

Comment: You don't need special tools if you are able to use a DB per test - JPA/Hibernate have DDL generation to drop and create tables when the persistence unit starts.

Comment: Question is – do we have new and fresh PU on each test?

Comment: Doesn't matter - you can control schema generation and the options via javax.persistence.Persistence.generateSchema on the fly:  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html . So you can drop+create all tables in setup/tear down per test or suite